# Java how to build a stream on top of an existing interface

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an existing interface that allows me to access a theoretically infinite collection as follows:

```
List<Element> retrieve(int start, int end);

//example
retrieve(5, 10); // retrieves the elements 5 through 10.
```

Now I would like to build a Java stream on top of this existing interface so that I can stream as many elements as I need without requesting a large list at once.

How would I go about doing this?

I looked at examples of Java streams and all I can find are examples of how to create stream from collections that are completely in memory. I currently load in 30 elements at a time and do the necessary processing but it would be cleaner if I could abstract that logic away and just return a stream instead.

Comment: how would you implement that `retrieve` btw? It's obvious if your `Collection` implements `RandomAccess`, but if it does not...

Comment: also if you really want to return a Stream, why not simply `skip(5).limit(10)`?

Comment: You probably want one of the static factory methods of Stream, like [Stream.generate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate%28java.util.function.Supplier%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Chunk implements Supplier<Element> {
    private final Generator generator;
    private final int chunkSize;
    private List<Element> list = Collections.emptyList();
    private int index = 0;

    public Chunk(Generator generator, int chunkSize) {
        assert chunkSize > 0;
        this.generator = generator;
        this.chunkSize = chunkSize;
    }

    @Override
    public Element get() {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            list = generator.retrieve(index, index + chunkSize);
            index += chunkSize;
        }
        return list.remove(0);
    }
}
```

Here I'm assuming `retrieve` returns a mutable list. If not then you'd need to create a new `ArrayList` or equivalent at this point.

This can be used as `Stream.generate(new Chuck(generator, 30))`. It generates an infinite stream starting at index 0. You could add a constructor that allows the starting index to be set if that would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you can't edit `retrieve` method.

You can do this:

```
IntStream.iterate(1, x -> x + 1).mapToObj(x -> retrieve(x, x).get(0))
```

If one term of the sequence depends on the previous term, this would mean recalculating every term up to `n` if you want the `n`th term.

This slightly solves the problem by getting it in chunks of 100:

```
IntStream.iterate(1, x -> x + 1).mapToObj(x -> retrieve(1 + (x - 1) * 100, x * 100)).flatMap(List::stream)
```

If you can edit what's behind that interface, you can just make that return a `Stream<Element>`, using `IntStream.iterate` as above.

Comment: Wouldn't this be an infinite stream without a short-circuiting operation? Basically, the chunks range should be the parameters for short-circuiting somehow.

Comment: @nullpointer doesn’t OP want exactly an infinite stream? OP can simply add a `limit` after that and specify how many he wants.